# Change numerical Data to Categorical Data - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which has a numerical column "amount". The amount varies from 0 to 20000. I want to change it into categorical variable which defines a range. So, the categorical variable would be :

1. Between 0-1000$
2. Between 1000-2000$ and so on.. till 19000-20000$

I am unable to figure out how to change the column. I can change it to a binary values like this :

```
months["value"] = np.where(months['amount']>=450, 'yes', 'no')
```

But, how to do it for categorical variable having more than 2 values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4000,5000,4000,9000,5,11040]})

df['D'] = pd.cut(df['B'], range(0, 21000, 1000))
print (df)
       B               D
0   4000    (3000, 4000]
1   5000    (4000, 5000]
2   4000    (3000, 4000]
3   9000    (8000, 9000]
4      5       (0, 1000]
5  11040  (11000, 12000]
```