# How to convert continous data to Categorical in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numeric, categorical-data, continuous

All,

My dataset looks like following, and I Would like to add one column which can convert my last column i.e Day_of_The_week to Mon, Tue, Wed.
Note: Day_of_the_week include 5 days : Mon,Tue,Wed,Thurs,Fri. I checked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659073/change-numerical-data-to-categorical-data-pandas) but couldn't figure out how to implement in my dataframe

[image]

**I would like to convert my pandas dataframe as below:**
[image]

Being a newbie to python,if you could provide explanation, that will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`calendar.day_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name) + [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

You can construct a dictionary and then map your integer series to a list of day strings:

```
import pandas as pd
from calendar import day_name
from collections import deque

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day_of_the_week': [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6]})

days = deque(day_name)
days.rotate(df['Day_of_the_week'].iat[0])  # rotate days
days_map = dict(enumerate(days))           # construct dictionary

df['Day_Factor'] = df['Day_of_the_week'].map(days_map)

print(df)

   Day_of_the_week Day_Factor
0                2     Monday
1                3    Tuesday
2                4  Wednesday
3                4  Wednesday
4                5   Thursday
5                6     Friday
6                6     Friday
```

Comment: Thanks! The dictionary key's  assigned 0 to Friday. I would like to assign key 6 to Friday. Is there a way to do that ? I would like my dictionary to start with 2 as Monday and ends at Key 6- Friday.

Comment: @biggboss2019, Yes, as you can see that's what my logic does, you are rotating days by 2 days. Since the `day_name` has Monday at index 0, but you want it at index 2. To hardcode this, use `2` instead of `df['Day_of_the_week'].iat[0]`.

Comment: Great. Thanks!!